# Looking for free webforms Report compopnent for Table

Tags: .net, winforms, report

I'm using some old Table Activex with Report / printing and even graphics to easy create useful reports. It' looking like that (Look pictures in the bottom of message)

But using so heavy ActiveX controls for it is a bit weird way. Is there something free like that for .NET Winforms ? Something to display the printable report based on my table.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If your using SQL Server you can use SQL Reporting Services. Otherwise what dB are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard Visual Studio Report Viewer Control. It allows you to build local (embedded) reports using almost any datasource you can think of. Look for more information on

- MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671(v=vs.100).aspx
- http://gotreportviewer.com/
- or [Google for ReportViewer](https://www.google.com/#output=search&q=ReportViewer)